# Generate content to display on an ePaper display from Android App

Tags: android, webview, bitmap, epub

This is a home-brew project of mine. The idea is to have an epaper display to display an ebook opened from an Android phone. The connection between the epaper can be wired or wireless - it doesn't really matter because I can take care of both. (I know that something similar is available - eInkCase, but hey, I don't want to buy it).

The ePaper can take a binary format which is basically a downsampled picture from a BitMap. I've finished the conversion and have tested displaying some pages of a book on it by hard-coding the text content of several pages.

Now the hard part is to display an ebook as it is read on the Android phone. The ebook format I'm aiming for is ePub to begin with. I've researched some apps and understood that a WebView is used to displayed the content.

My question is:

- Is it sensible to obtain the text content of the WebView to generate a bitmap equivalent using some JavaScript?
- Is there any other way to obtain the content of the WebView?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

how are you getting data from ePaper? can you convert it to String?

You can generate dynamic string to create a temporary html file and load it at runtime. e.g code

```
<WebView
                android:id="@+id/WebViewToDisplay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false" />
```

Load data into WebView

```
WebView webViewDisplay;
StringBuffer LoadWEb1;

webViewDisplay = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewToDisplay);
LoadWEb1 = new StringBuffer();
LoadWEb1.append("<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p>");
//Sample code to read parameters at run time
String strName = "Test Paragraph";
LoadWEb1.append("<br/><p>"+strName+"</p>");
String result = LoadWEb1.append("</body></html>").toString();
        WebSettings webSettings = webViewDisplay.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewDisplay.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            webViewDisplay.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            webViewDisplay.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        }

        webViewDisplay.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html", "utf-8",
                null);
        //To load local file directly from assets folder use below code
        //webViewDisplay.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutapp.html");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Maybe I wasn't clear in my description above. What I need to do is the reverse of what you just described. I want to sent data TO the epaper. Do I understand correctly that this is not the example code is trying to do?